# ElementStyle error for DataGridComboBoxColumn in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I'm trying to alter the `ElementStyle` of a DataGrid ComboBox column.  Supposedly the Style is really of type `TextBlock` when the control is not being edited.  So as shown in other examples, I've tried:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

When this is embedded in my `DataGridComboBoxColumn` definition, I get this weird error message:

> 'TextBlock' TargetType does not match type of element 'TextBlockComboBox'.

What exactly is a `TextBlockComboBox`? Or more importantly, how can I get to the `ElementStyle`, because targeting `ComboBox` doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ElementStyle` in this case should be the type of `ComboBox`. We have two types of DataGrid, which it operates - `DataGridRow` and `DataGridCell`, the first is a line, the second cell. Therefore, by default, everything is composed of cells of the type `DataGridCell` not `TextBlock's`.

To determine the type of another column, use `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Therefore `DataGridComboBoxColumn` maybe is defined as:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1.5*" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Position2">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxColumn" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

With this set can be any type of control.

In your case, you need to create a style for `DataGridCell`:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleForCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

And using like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColumn" 
                        CellStyle="{StaticResource StyleForCell}"
                        Header="Position"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Position}" />
```

Comment: using `TemplateColumn` works, so I will mark this as answer.  I still don't understand exactly why my code failed, since it came from another web solution.  But one solution is all I need :)

Answer (score 4):

`TextBlockComboBox` is an internal type to `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. I also don't know how to get that type styled but you can trick `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle` by using a `ComboBox` style that looks like a `TextBlock`:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockComboBoxStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                           Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the above style I use a globally-defined `TextBlock` style defined elsewhere and bind the `Text` property of the `ComboBox`. Finally you can use the style like so:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBlockComboBoxStyle}"
                        EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" />
```

The `EditingElementStyle` in this case is again a globally-defined `ComboBox` style defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Supposedly the Style is really of type TextBlock when the control is not being edited.

No there is an hack in the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to allow the use of the same style for `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle`. You have to use `ComboBox` as the target type.